# NetBeans 7.0 , JUnit and Glassfish Embedded 3.1: Does not work

Tags: java, netbeans, jakarta-ee, glassfish, glassfish-embedded

I am trying to JUnit Test a J2EE Web Application with NB 7.0, JUnit and the embedded Glassfish Server in a Win7Professional machine.

I broke it down to just test a plain simple Hello-World Web App with a single Session Bean.

I have the glasfish-embedded-static-shell.jar in my classpath, and also tried to use the glassfish-embedded-all-3.1 but it also didn't work.

Now here's the code I use to test the bean:

```
import javax.ejb.embeddable.EJBContainer;
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public class SimpleBeanTest {

private static EJBContainer container;

public SimpleBeanTest() {
}

@BeforeClass
public static void setUpClass() throws Exception {
    container = javax.ejb.embeddable.EJBContainer.createEJBContainer();
}

@AfterClass
public static void tearDownClass() throws Exception {
    container.close();
}

@Test
public void testCountToThree() throws Exception {
   System.out.println("countToThree");
   SimpleBean instance = (SimpleBean) container.getContext().lookup("java:global/classes/SimpleBean");
   int expResult = 0;
   int result = instance.countToThree();
   assertEquals(expResult, result);

}
}
```

And here's what comes out of it:

```
19.06.2011 09:31:56 com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.CommonClassLoaderServiceImpl findDerbyClient
INFO: Cannot find javadb client jar file, derby jdbc driver will not be available by default.
19.06.2011 09:31:56 org.glassfish.flashlight.impl.provider.FlashlightProbeProviderFactory processXMLProbeProviders
SCHWERWIEGEND: MNTG0301:Cannot process XML ProbeProvider, xml = META-INF/gfprobe-provider.xml
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Provider already mapped glassfish:javamail:smtp-transport

(StackTrace here)

19.06.2011 09:31:57 org.glassfish.flashlight.impl.provider.FlashlightProbeProviderFactory processXMLProbeProviders
SCHWERWIEGEND: MNTG0301:Cannot process XML ProbeProvider, xml = META-INF/mojarra-jsf-api-probe-provider.xml
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Provider already mapped glassfish:jsf:faces-servlet

(StackTrace here)

19.06.2011 09:31:57 org.glassfish.flashlight.impl.provider.FlashlightProbeProviderFactory processXMLProbeProviders
SCHWERWIEGEND: MNTG0301:Cannot process XML ProbeProvider, xml = jersey-gf-server-probe-provider.xml
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Provider already mapped glassfish:jersey:server-hidden

(StackTrace here)

19.06.2011 09:31:57 org.glassfish.flashlight.impl.provider.FlashlightProbeProviderFactory processXMLProbeProviders
SCHWERWIEGEND: MNTG0301:Cannot process XML ProbeProvider, xml = jersey-gf-statsprovider-probe-provider.xml
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Provider already mapped glassfish:jersey:server

(StackTrace here)

19.06.2011 09:31:57 org.glassfish.ha.store.spi.BackingStoreFactoryRegistry register
INFO: Registered org.glassfish.ha.store.adapter.cache.ShoalBackingStoreProxy for persistence-type = replicated in BackingStoreFactoryRegistry
19.06.2011 09:31:57 org.glassfish.ha.store.spi.BackingStoreFactoryRegistry register
INFO: Registered org.glassfish.ha.store.adapter.cache.ShoalBackingStoreProxy for persistence-type = replicated in BackingStoreFactoryRegistry
19.06.2011 09:31:57 com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.AppServerStartup run
SCHWERWIEGEND: Startdienst konnte nicht gestartet werden: com.sun.enterprise.naming.GlassFishNamingBuilder
19.06.2011 09:31:57 com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.AppServerStartup run
INFO: GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1 (43) Startzeit: Embedded (597ms), Startdienste(929ms), gesamt(1.526ms)
19.06.2011 09:31:57 org.glassfish.admin.mbeanserver.JMXStartupService$JMXConnectorsStarterThread run
INFO: JMXStartupService: JMXConnector system is disabled, skipping.
```

**UPDATE:**
And this is the exception which would be thrown by any test:

```
No EJBContainer provider available
Provider named org.glassfish.ejb.embedded.EJBContainerProviderImpl threw unexpected exception at create EJBContainer: 
java.lang.RuntimeException
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: AMX Booter MBean is already registered: amx-support:type=boot-amx
    at org.glassfish.internal.embedded.Server.<init>(Server.java:290)
    at org.glassfish.internal.embedded.Server.<init>(Server.java:66)
    at org.glassfish.internal.embedded.Server$Builder.build(Server.java:176)

(Stack Trace here)

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: AMX Booter MBean is already registered: amx-support:type=boot-amx
```

I have reinstalled NetBeans twice and it doesn't works either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue and I did the following:

1) I installed Glassfish 3.1.1 and linked it to my project. First I added the server with Tools - Servers - Add Server... Then I right-clicked my EJB project and selected Properties - Run - Glassfish 3.1.1
2) In my EJB pom.xml I use this dependency (make sure the systemPath variable points to the correct file):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.extras</groupId>
    <artifactId>glassfish-embedded-static-shell</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.1</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${glassfish.embedded-static-shell.jar}</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

3) In my EJB pom.xml I **removed** the dependency other people said I have to add it if I get the errors "Provider already mapped..."

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.extras</groupId>
    <artifactId>glassfish-embedded-all</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

That's it! Now my EJB JUnit tests with JPA 2 work like a charm! Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the server is starting ok (some of those exceptions are expected, but I can't confirm if all of them are).

- Are you running the tests cases with "Run > Test Project"?
- Is the JUnit GUI popping up?
- Is JUnit installed? Netbeans 7.0 now asks if you want to download JUnit because of licensing Issues...
- Can you run unit tests that don't need the embedded container?

Try to follow those steps: http://javadude.wordpress.com/2010/02/22/tutorial-most-simple-test-application-for-embedded-glassfish-netbeans-hudson/ (forget about the Hudson part). The IDE should take care of including the dependencies for you.

Oh, another thing, since you are using Windows, it won't hurt to try to run Netbeans as Admin (right click option) and see what happens.

Cheers,

**Update**

Maybe you are hitting [this](http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-16285) bug:

See if starting the container like this works for you:

```
@BeforeClass
public static void setUpClass() throws Exception {
    Map<String, Object> p = new HashMap<String, Object>();       
    p.put(EJBContainer.APP_NAME, "foo");
    container = EJBContainer.createEJBContainer(p);
}
```

Comment: Hi Anthony, I tried the tutorial with same results.
Yes, JUNit is installed, it came with the NB installation, when I tried to run the tests the GUI appears.

Comment: @DGalvis. Hi, so what's the problem, is it hanging? Is it even displaying "countToThree"?

Comment: I tried to install NB full edition with no luck.
Using administrative privileges doesn't work either.

Comment: @Anthony when I run the tests they throw this exception: "No EJBContainer available Provider named org.glassfish.ejb.embedded.EJBContainerProviderImpl threw unexpected exception at create EJBContainer:..."

Comment: @DGalvis, any lucky with the above code? If not, I would download a new version of Glassfish and include the `glassfish-embedded-static-shell.jar` in the classpath as you did before.

Comment: @Anthony: no luck with the above workaround. I'm downloading the previous version of Glassfish (V3). I'll try the latest one tomorrow too. thank you for your ideas :) +1

Comment: @DGalvis. Ok. Another thing that crossed my mind is to check if the application is targeting a GlassFish Domain (deploy it inside Netbeans to make sure). If not, just use `glassfish-embedded-all.jar` and kill the external dependencies alltogether.